# I am getting value error in python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    n = input()
    for i in range(len(n)):
        first = n[:i]
        second = n[i:]
        print(type(first))
        print(type(int(first)))
```

Why I am getting ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztGzR.png)

Comment: is the value of `t` you entered an integer? Because that line probably has the error. Check the input

Comment: Maybe - You have pressed entered without inputting number, because of which the input  is empty or ''

Comment: Yes, the value of t is an integer. If I didn't take t value as integer then how I run the test cases

Comment: The problem is not with the code so much as with what input you are providing the code. `int` raises the `ValueError` when `input()` returns the empty string. You could catch the exception, but it would probably make sense to figure out *why* `input` is returning the empty string in the first place.

Comment: @RitulSingh next time please include the full stack trace in the question, rather than linking to an image of it.  You successfully fooled almost everyone into thinking the exception was raised on the first line (`int(input())`) instead of the last line (`int(first)`) because the error you included doesn't include the line of code that raised it.  It would also be useful to include the exact strings you inputted in order to reproduce the problem, or better yet, modify your code to include the strings you used for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

As the error says, you entered an empty value (`''`), that the built-in function `int` isn't able to convert.

---

If you want to check if `t` is acceptable (an integer) you can use `.isdigit`:

```
>>> '1'.isdigit()
True
>>> ''.isdigit()
False
>>> 'Hello1'.isdigit()
False
```

Or maybe use a `try`/`except` block:

```
try:
    t = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Error, your input wasn't a number")
```

---

As your screenshot shows, the error gets raised at:

```
print(type(int(first)))
```

but the reason is the same, you can solve it with the `try`/`except` block above.

```
try:
    print(type(int(first)))
except ValueError:
    pass # Simply do nothing, since an empty element of n was reached
```

Comment: Adding to this, you can check to see whether the input is unacceptable and continue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, is there anything else that I should add?

Comment: That's all up to you though, if you want to accept a particular group of numbers and not all integers, you could add the needed check. Looking at the edited answer, it would be better if you would use `try/except` so that it is readable for others (of course it is ambiguous) or you could just use `isdigit()` to make it short.

Comment: Hey FLAK_ZOSO, I am not converting the value of t. I am changing the value n in the integer. You can see the code here https://onlinegdb.com/V_P23Amli

Comment: In this case I don't get what you're trying to do, have you tried some debugging?

Comment: This isn't the problem.  Although it's hard to tell at a glance because OP didn't include the *full* stack trace or say what their input was.  :P

Answer (score 0):

For purposes of debugging, let's just focus on a single iteration and assign a reasonable value to `n` that represents the sort of thing you expect the user to `input()`.  (When people ask you for an "MRE", this is the type of thing they mean -- a small piece of code that you can run to immediately demonstrate the problem.)

```
n = "12345"
for i in range(len(n)):
    first = n[:i]
    second = n[i:]
    print(type(first))
    print(type(int(first)))
```

It breaks here:

```
    print(type(int(first)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Why is that?  Well, let's do a little more printing:

```
    print(f"first = n[:{i}] = {repr(first)}")
```

gets us:

```
first = n[:0] = ''
```

And indeed, the slice `n[:0]` is an empty string, which you can't convert to an `int`.  What you probably want to do is reduce your `range` so that it starts at 1 instead of 0:

```
n = "12345"
for i in range(1, len(n)):
    first = n[:i]
    second = n[i:]
    print(f"first = n[:{i}] = {repr(first)}")
    print(f"second = n[{i}:] = {repr(second)}")
```

prints:

```
first = n[:1] = '1'
second = n[1:] = '2345'
first = n[:2] = '12'
second = n[2:] = '345'
first = n[:3] = '123'
second = n[3:] = '45'
first = n[:4] = '1234'
second = n[4:] = '5'
```